# Как в java проверить содержит ли строка числа в определённом диапазоне

Tags: java

у нас есть список строк,пользователь должен ввести минимальное и максимальное числа, после чего программа проверяет содержится ли в строке число в диапазоне от минимального, до максимального

Comment: [String.contains(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)).

Comment: @post_zeew, не годится.

Comment: @Qwertiy, Почему?

Comment: @post_zeew, contains проверяет на вхождение подстроки. А в вопросе числа. Есть строка `Тут 123 что-то 888 с 65 числами`. Чем `contains` поможет определить, есть ли в строки числа в диапазоне `16 to 311`?

Comment: @Qwertiy, Вы серьезно думали, что приведенный метод будет непосредственно решать поставленную задачу? Разумеется, нет. Ну, циклы там есть и все такое. Но это далеко неоптимальное решение, поэтому оно и опубликовано не как ответ. Так-то конечно нужно извлечь числа из строки, ну и так далее.

Comment: @post_zeew, я вообще не вижу места этому методу в решении. Регуляркой выбираем все числа из строки, в получившемся массиве преобразуем строки в числа и сравниваем с границами. Никакого contains.

Comment: @Qwertiy, А я (чисто в теории) – вижу.

Comment: @post_zeew, перебрать все числа в диапазоне и их искать? Не сработает: строка `12345`, число `234`. Contains возвращает bool, так что даже окружающие символы не проверить.

Comment: @Qwertiy, Про это я не подумал. Тогда да, согласен.

Answer (score 3):

В вашем вопросе скорей всего помогут регулярные выражения.
Регулярные выражения (англ. regular expressions) — формальный язык поиска и осуществления манипуляций с подстроками в тексте, основанный на использовании метасимволов (символов-джокеров, англ. wildcard characters). По сути это строка-образец (англ. pattern, по-русски её часто называют «шаблоном», «маской»), состоящая из символов и метасимволов и задающая правило поиска.

```
    import java.util.regex.*;

    String msg = "Строка с цифрами 12345";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(msg);

    while(matcher.find()){
        Integer result = new Integer(msg.substring(matcher.start(),matcher.end()));
        if(result > 100) System.out.println( result + " > 100" );
    }
```